# Different plots are overlapped

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I'm using matplotlib and nltk to plot the freq dist of different authors but it seems two plots are being plotted in the plot. How can I fix this by creating another separate plot for author-name freq dist?

Here is some of my code:

```
# Visualizing the # of data sets being posted every year from 2002 to 2019
num_bins = 18
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(year_list, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('# of Sets')
plt.title(r'Number of Published Data Sets from 2002 - 2019')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
# plt.show()


from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist


author_str = "".join(author_list)
fdist = FreqDist()
for word in word_tokenize(author_str):
    fdist[word.lower()] += 1
fdist.plot(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using subplots for plotting this.  I imagine that your `fdist` plot will add it to whatever axis instance is currently there as you are seeing.  It should be formatted in something like the following way:

```py
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(121)

# Your first plot stuff here

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)

# Your second plot here
```

Check out the [subplots examples here.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Alternatively, create a new figure instance using the `plt.figure()` command if you want the plots to be truly separate.  When you use the `plt.show()` command, it will show all of the open figure instances.

Comment: @yixin0829 Be sure you don’t forget to mark this answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question